# Error while trying to updat API with button click

Tags: json, swift, api

I'm trying to update API values with a button click. This is the update function:

```
func updateAPI() {
    withAnimation {
        model.allStocks = []
        for stock in depot.aktienKatArray {
            model.getStockData(for: stock.aKat_symbol ?? "")
            for allS in model.allStocks {
                if allS.metaData.symbol == stock.aKat_symbol {
                    stock.aKat_currPerShare = Double(allS.latestClose) ?? 0
                }
            }
        }
        PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
    }
}
```

I'm using two for .. in loops to assign the api value (latestClose) to the corresponding stock in the AktieKat Entity.
The view has an update button at the top and a list of stocks with the attribute aKat_currPerShare and every time I update the API (with button click) the aKat_currPerShare should get the updated latestClose value of the API.

The error message from the output in Xcode appears when the button is clicked:

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Meta Data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "Meta Data", intValue: nil) ("Meta Data").", underlyingError: nil))

This is my API Model:

```
final class APIModel: ObservableObject {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@Published var allStocks: [StockData] = []
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

@Published var stockEntities: [AktieKat] = []

init() {
    loadAllStocks()
}

func loadAllStocks() {
    allStocks = []
    stockEntities.forEach { stockEntity in
        getStockData(for: stockEntity.aKat_symbol ?? "")
    }
}

func getStockData(for symbol: String) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=\(symbol)&outputsize=full&apikey=\(APIKEY ?? "E11H9EDJNUB2N1UJ")")!

    URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .tryMap { element -> Data in
            guard let response = element.response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  response.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
            }
            return element.data
        }
        .decode(type: StockData.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .sink { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                return
            case .finished:
                return
            }
        } receiveValue: { [unowned self] returnedStocks in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.allStocks.append(returnedStocks)
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    
}
```

}

and these are the CodingKeys:

```
struct StockData: Codable {

var metaData: MetaData
var timeSeriesDaily: [String: TimeSeriesDaily]

//    var latestClose: String {
//        timeSeriesDaily.first?.value.close ?? ""
//    }

var latestClose: String {
    guard let mostRecentDate = timeSeriesDaily.keys.sorted(by: >).first else { return "" }
    return timeSeriesDaily[mostRecentDate]!.close
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case metaData = "Meta Data"
    case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
}

struct MetaData: Codable {
    let information: String
    let symbol: String
    let lastRefreshed: String
    let outputSize: String
    let timeZone: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case information = "1. Information"
        case symbol = "2. Symbol"
        case lastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
        case outputSize = "4. Output Size"
        case timeZone = "5. Time Zone"
    }
}

struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    var open: String
    var high: String
    var low: String
    var close: String
    var volume: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case open = "1. open"
        case high = "2. high"
        case low = "3. low"
        case close = "4. close"
        case volume = "5. volume"
    }
  }
}

{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "DAI.DEX",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-04-05",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2022-04-05": {
            "1. open": "64.4900",
            "2. high": "64.8200",
            "3. low": "62.6200",
            "4. close": "62.9600",
            "5. volume": "3425810"
        },
        "2022-04-04": {
            "1. open": "63.9900",
            "2. high": "64.5400",
            "3. low": "62.8100",
            "4. close": "64.2600",
            "5. volume": "2538008"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are aware that what you get is a decoding error from decoding the downloaded json? My guess is that the API returns an error message instead of the expected response so you need to handle that error and print it. Most likely something is wrong with your query

Comment: And stop tagging your questions with "swiftui" until the you have a question that is actually about SwiftUI

Comment: I'm sorry for the wrong Tag. I've added an JSON example below the CodingKeys, but what am I doing wrong? I don't know how to change the code.

Comment: We don't need the json really. You need to print what is returned from the call since it is most likely an error message and it can explain what is wrong with your query. You could of course print the url, `print(url.absoluteString)` and then copy and paste it into Postman or directly into your web browser and see what response you get but that is just a solution for this issue. Actually handling the error in your code is the preferred moving forward.

Comment: One thing that stands out is that you use `getStockData(for: stockEntity.aKat_symbol ?? "")`, that is call the function with an empty string if there is no symbol and then without any validation calls the API with this value. Do you know that the API accepts "" as a symbol???

Comment: I don't know if that is the problem, because when I add a stock with the getStockData function it adds the value of the latestClose to the aKat_currPerShare. But when I try to update these values I get this error and it doesn't update. If its helpful I can post how I add a stock with the API value

Comment: In `func updateAPI()` you have `model.getStockData(for: stock.aKat_symbol ?? "")`, and its use is incorrect.
`getStockData(...)` is an asynchronous function, you cannot use it as a synchronous function like you do. Fetching a particular symbol works well in my tests.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine but how can I use it in this case as an asynchronous function. I'm not that experienced in swift

Comment: Inside `tryMap` before the return add the code `if let s = String(data: element.data, encoding: .utf8) { print(s) }` to print the raw json response. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: Now it prints the raw json. For example if there are 4 stocks: For each stock the prices for the last 20+ years. So its a long list but the error is now not showing up

Comment: Does the decoding work as expected? If so you need to reproduce the error you have reported in your question for my code to be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test code to fetch stocks using Swift async/await concurrency framework (just for fun).

I know you said `I'm not that experienced in swift`, and
it will be **heavy** to understand at first. But learning how to use it pays off later on,
especially in this case, where you want to download a lot of info using a lot of network calls. Hope it helps, if not let me know and I'll delete my answer.

See also:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/updating_an_app_to_use_swift_concurrency

https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=2o3euotz

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct StockData: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here
    var metaData: MetaData?
    var timeSeriesDaily: [String: TimeSeriesDaily]?
    
    var latestClose: String {
        if let timeseries = timeSeriesDaily {
            guard let mostRecentDate = timeseries.keys.sorted(by: >).first else { return "" }
            return timeseries[mostRecentDate]!.close
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case metaData = "Meta Data"
        case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
    }
}

struct MetaData: Codable {
    let information: String
    let symbol: String
    let lastRefreshed: String
    let outputSize: String
    let timeZone: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case information = "1. Information"
        case symbol = "2. Symbol"
        case lastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
        case outputSize = "4. Output Size"
        case timeZone = "5. Time Zone"
    }
}

struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
    var open: String
    var high: String
    var low: String
    var close: String
    var volume: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case open = "1. open"
        case high = "2. high"
        case low = "3. low"
        case close = "4. close"
        case volume = "5. volume"
    }
}

// for testing
struct AktieKat: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here
    var aKat_symbol: String?
    var aKat_currPerShare: Double?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case aKat_symbol, aKat_currPerShare
    }
}

final class APIModel: ObservableObject {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    let apikey = "E11H9EDJNUB2N1UJ"
    
    @Published var allStocks: [StockData] = []
    @Published var stockEntities: [AktieKat] = []
    
    init() {
        // for testing
        self.stockEntities = [AktieKat(aKat_symbol: "AAP"), AktieKat(aKat_symbol: "MSFT")]
        Task {
            await loadAllStocks()
        }
    }
    
    func loadAllStocks() async {
        Task{@MainActor in
            allStocks = await loadAllStocks(for: stockEntities)
        }
    }
    
    // fetch all StockData concurrently
    func loadAllStocks(for arr: [AktieKat]) async -> [StockData] {
        var results: [StockData] = []
        // get all stocks concurrently
        await withTaskGroup(of: (StockData?).self) { group -> Void in
            arr.forEach { stockEntity in
                group.addTask {
                    await (self.getStockData(for: stockEntity.aKat_symbol))
                }
            }
            for await value in group {
                if let stock = value {
                    results.append(stock)
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }
    
    // fetch one StockData for one symbol
    func getStockData(for theSymbol: String?) async -> StockData? {
        if let symbol = theSymbol,
           let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=\(symbol)&outputsize=full&apikey=\(apikey)") {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                return try JSONDecoder().decode(StockData.self, from: data)
            }
            catch { print(error) }
        }
        return nil
    }
   
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var apiModel = APIModel()
    
    // for testing
    @State var depot_aktienKatArray = [AktieKat(aKat_symbol: "IBM")]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 33){
            Button("update") {
                updateAPI()
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered).padding(20)
            
            if apiModel.allStocks.count == 0 {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Text("\(apiModel.allStocks.count) stocks fetched")
            }
            
            List(apiModel.allStocks) { stock in
               HStack (spacing: 20) {
                   Text(stock.metaData?.symbol ?? "no data")
                   Text(stock.latestClose).foregroundColor(.red)
               }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // not sure what you want to do here
    func updateAPI() {
        withAnimation {
            Task {@MainActor in
                apiModel.allStocks = []
                apiModel.allStocks = await apiModel.loadAllStocks(for: depot_aktienKatArray)
                for stock in apiModel.allStocks {
                    if let index = depot_aktienKatArray.firstIndex(where: {$0.aKat_symbol == stock.metaData.symbol}) {
                        depot_aktienKatArray[index].aKat_currPerShare = Double(stock.latestClose) ?? 0
                    }
                }
//                PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
            }
        }
    }
       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Unfortunately I get the error message:  keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Meta Data", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Meta Data\", intValue: nil) (\"Meta Data\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Well I'm really surprised you get a decoding error. My code works very well for me. Nevertheless, can you show where you get this error, and with what particular symbol. As a check, in `StockData` can you use `var metaData: MetaData?`

Comment: Not surprising at all imo since I believe this is more likely an issue with the query string being sent to the API rather than a concurrency issue. I mean, why would a concurrency issue result in a decoding error?

Comment: yes, I agree, but why does my code works for me and not the OP. I suspect this is not due to my code (famous last words).

Comment: The problem may be due to the `apikey` used. For example this query with the `apikey=demo`
 gives an error because it does not allow the data from this symbol.
`https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=APP&outputsize=full&apikey=demo`
 However, using
 `apikey=E11H9EDJNUB2N1UJ` works well. I'll update my answer for optional for `metaData` and `timeSeriesDaily`

Comment: It could be a more UI related issue, it works fine the first time but not the second time when an update is requested via a button click if I understand the question properly.

Comment: I changed the function of the api from Time series daily to daily quotes, I don’t know exactly what the problem was but now it works. Maybe I try your code later again to see if it works with the daily quotes @workingdogsupportUkraine. Thank you for your efforts

Comment: Ok, so if I understand you correctly, you were not getting the error from my code.
 I would be interested if someone could run just my code and report any errors.
 P.S, I could not find any info on `daily quote` query function in the docs.